# Stylus-Activated Pie Menus? Tablet Mode Sculpting?

Tags: interface, sculpting

How to access pie menus when in Tablet mode?

In Tablet mode, the keyboard will not be accessible, thus requiring access to the Pie Menus via the stylus pen. I need these menus for Viewpoint shortcuts, switching design modes, etc.

Please Help. TIA

Answer (score 3):

You can map one of the pen or tablet buttons in Wacom Tablet Properties to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> as per [this list of Blender shortcuts](https://www.republicworld.com/technology-news/apps/blender-shortcut-keys-list-of-all-the-blender-commands-that-come-handy.html). Note that you can create a specific setting just for Blender.

1. Go to Wacom Tablet Properties
2. Optionally, set a specific application
3. Select the dropdown menu for the button you plan on changing
4. Select "Keystroke..."
5. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, optionally name the shortcut key, and then click on OK

(click images to enlarge)
[image: Image of Wacom Tablet Properties with an arrow to the setting I plan on changing]

[image: Image of the Menu item to select, "Keystroke..."]

[image: Image of the Dialog where the shortcut can be picked]